# Verifying the solution to $R\dot{Q(t)}+\frac{1}{C}Q(t) = V_{o}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

In the text Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems the charging of a capacitor is described the following differential equation in $(1.2)$. 
$$(1.2)$$

$$R\dot{Q(t)}+\frac{1}{C}Q(t) = V_{o}$$

Considering our DE in $(1.2)$, we have the initial parameters are as follows: $Q(t)$ is the charge of the capacitor, $C$ is it's capacitance, $V_{0}$ is the voltage of the battery, and $R$ is the resistance of the wire.

$Problem$: Compute $Q(t)$ assuming the capacitor is uncharged at $t \, = 0$.

$Solution$:
Considering $(1.2)$, I initially redefined the variable for capacitance as follows: $Q(t)$ initially becomes $Q(y)$. Now $(1.2)$ becomes the following in $(1.3)$ Also we take the initial assumption that our capacitor is uncharged at $t \, = 0$ therefore allowing us to have an initial condition

$$(1.3)$$
$$R \dot{Q(y)}+\frac{1}{C}Q(t) = V_{o}   \, \, \, \, \, t(0)=t_{0}.$$

Looking at $(1.3)$ one can initially observe on the LHS that $(1.3)$ initially becomes:
$$R \frac{Q(y)}{Q(x)}+\frac{1}{C}Q(t) = V_{o}   \, \, \, \, \, t(0)=t_{0}$$.

From our prior observations we can at arrive at the following conclusion:
$$\int R{Q(y)}\frac{1}{C}Q(t) = \int V_{o}dQ(x)  \, \, \, \, \, , t(0)=t_{0}.$$.

Elementary ruses finally allow us to arrive at our solution:
$$dQ(t) = \int_{t_{o}}^{o} RdQ(y) + \frac{1}{c}Q(y)$$

Comment: why not simply integrate wrt t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$
\tau = \frac{t}{RC} ~~\mbox{and}~~ Q_{\max} = V_0 C
$$

So that your original ODE becomes

$$
\frac{{\rm d} Q}{{\rm d}\tau} + Q = Q_{\max}
$$

which can be rearranged as

$$
\frac{{\rm d}Q}{Q_\max - Q} = {\rm d} \tau
$$

integrating with the condition $Q(\tau = 0) = 0$ we arrive to

$$
-\tau = \int_{0}^Q \frac{{\rm d}Q'}{Q'- Q_\max} = \ln\frac{Q_\max - Q}{Q_\max}
$$

Solving for $Q$:

$$
Q(t) = V_0C(1 - e^{-t/RC})
$$

Comment: What went wrong with my initial approach was it due to me misdefining the IVP ?

Comment: @Zophikel So far I can tell you were a bit confused with the definition of the dynamical variables in your problem: $Q$ in this case only depends on $t$

Comment: Ahhh all right I haven't had much training experience with physical systems

Comment: @Zophikel Well, in that case let me give you a couple of hints: $RC$ is a characteristic time-scale, and $Q_\max$ is the maximum charge that the capacitor will ever get

Comment: Interesting what is a characteristic time-scale ?

Comment: @Zophikel A measure of time that marks something intrinsic of the systems happening. In this case it means the time in which the capacitor reaches 63% of its maximum charge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57143/discussion-between-zophikel-and-caverac).